# Add automatic createdAt and updatedAt timestamps in migration

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm doing a Sequelize migration which adds a new table.
In this table I want to add the timestamps createdAt and updatedAt that are automatically updated and my migrations works using literals like this:

```
createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
},
updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
},
```

I've to only add `timestamps: true` in the options but the timestamps are not automatically updated.

Can I do this without using literals?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar problem in setting the `defaultValue` for the timestamp fields.

I came across this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/645 which suggests calling `Sequelize.fn('NOW')` to automatically update the timestamps.

Seemed to work in my case.

Comment: defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW') in migrations works like a charm! It must be added to documentation!

Comment: For info, this also works in seeders (sequelize v6.x stable)